# <s:select> drop down issue when using default option as empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, struts2

I am using Map to populate Struts2 tag `<s:select >` , observed that when there are multiple submission of the form a blank line gets appened at the end of the list.
For instance, if Map has 2 key value pairs it show 3 records and append a blank record in the bottom(not at the top--for default case).

```
    Item 1 
    Item 2 
    <-blank->

    <s:select id="bankAccountId"
    name="accountBean.recordDetails.BankAcct.bankAcctId" label="" 
    headerKey="" headerValue="" list="accountBean.bankAccountMap" 
    listKey="key" listValue="value" />  

    <select name="accountBean.recordDetails.BankAcct.bankAcctId">
        <option value=""></option> 
        <option value="51089">BANK XXXX123</option>
    </select>



<select name="accountBean.recordDetails.BankAcct.bankAcctId" id="bankAccountId"> <option value="-1" selected="selected">Default values</option> <option value="77746">Details XXXXXX2246</option> <option value="-1" selected="selected"> </option> <---this default value gets appened in the end... </select>
```

When i use s:select attribute `emptyOption="true"` same issue is observed but when `emptyOption="false"` top element becomes non-empty(which i dont want).
on re-submission 
`<option value="" selected="selected"> </option>` extral option gets appened if prior to resubmission default/empty value was chosen..
Can this be handeled by javascript or jQuery??

Comment: A comment on the last question: mishaps on the server side should not be fixed by adding some client-side code to the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As things seem, I think the problem is that you are adding the default value to the map after submission, so in the next rendering of the page, it already contains that item. Usually, you should refill your map in your `prepare` method, that way the `-1` key won't be in the map.

Comment: Yes, in this case, you need to do null checks